# Так же или также? Как правильно пишется?

Tags: грамматика, союзы, также

> Бронирование получилось сделать легко, без заминок, подтверждение
> пришло сразу, с корректной информацией, так(?)же поступило подтверждение
> в день бронирования, поступил запрос об обратной связи с возможностью
> оставить отзыв.

Я думаю, что здесь идёт как союз, поэтому слитно пишется, верно?

Comment: 1. Не понял, сколько было подтверждений. День бронирования, это день оформления брони? Если так, то сначала (через минуты) пришло первое подтверждение, а потом (но до 23:59) пришло второе? 2. Вы хотите сами написать этот текст, или Вы хотите понять - не ошибся ли автор текста?

Comment: Пишется раздельно, если можно добавить "само".

Comment: Бронирование получилось сделать легко, без заминок, подтверждение пришло сразу, с корректной информацией. Также поступило подтверждение в день бронирования, поступил запрос об обратной связи с возможностью оставить отзыв.

Answer (score 1):

Можно исправить (для лучшего понимания), как было предложено в комментарии:

*Бронирование получилось сделать легко, без заминок, подтверждение пришло сразу, с корректной информацией. **Также** поступило подтверждение в день бронирования, поступил запрос об обратной связи с возможностью оставить отзыв.*

Это союз ***ТАКЖЕ*** со значением союза ***И***, сравнить: *Поступило подтверждение ***и*** в день бронирования...*

Раздельное написание ***ТАК ЖЕ*** невозможно, так как местоимение ТАК (без частицы ЖЕ) не имеет каких-либо синтаксических связей в этом предложении.

Answer (score 1):

Можно и так и так, но будет разный смысл:

> Бронирование получилось сделать легко, без заминок, подтверждение
> пришло сразу, с корректной информацией, так же (так же легко, без заминок) поступило
> подтверждение в день бронирования, поступил запрос об обратной связи с
> возможностью оставить отзыв.

> Бронирование получилось сделать легко, без заминок, подтверждение
> пришло сразу, с корректной информацией, также (в то же время) поступило
> подтверждение в день бронирования, поступил запрос об обратной связи с
> возможностью оставить отзыв.

Comment: Ваш ответ верный, но я бы уточнил содержание скобок. *Бронирование получилось сделать легко, без заминок, подтверждение пришло сразу, с корректной информацией, так же **(так же как и предыдущее подтверждение: сразу и с корректной информацией)** поступило подтверждение в день бронирования, поступил запрос об обратной связи с возможностью оставить отзыв.*  *Бронирование получилось сделать легко, без заминок, подтверждение пришло сразу, с корректной информацией, также (в то же время, **еще, кроме того**) поступило подтверждение в день бронирования ...*